# Optimizations for Polygon Intersection Finding

Tags: python, optimization, computational-geometry

I have ~1 billion 2D polygons, each with between 5 and 2000 vertices, laid out on a geographical map. I want to generate cutout masks of these polygons in the bounded range of a quadrangle which is a square portion of the map. I have a naively-coded solution which collects all the polygons that overlap the quadrangle bounds, then creates a mask and draws each of the polygons which it has found to be overlapping with the quadrangle bounds.

relevant code:

```
def generate_alteration_layers_by_extent(alterations, poly_locators, extents, output_res=1000):
    left, right, upper, lower = extents
    query_rectangle = pysal.cg.shapes.Rectangle(left, lower, right, upper)
    num_layers = len(shapes_by_alterations)
    boxed_alteration_layers = []
    for i, (alteration, poly_locator) in enumerate(zip(alterations, poly_locators)):
        print "computing overlapping polygons"
        overlapping_polys = poly_locator.overlapping(query_rectangle)
        print "drawing polygons onto mask"
        img = Image.new('L', (output_res, output_res), 0)
        polys = [np.array(map(list, poly.vertices)) for poly in overlapping_polys]
        for poly in polys: 
            # normalize to the dimensions of img
            poly[:,0] -= left;  poly[:,0] *= (right-left); poly[:,0] *= output_res
            poly[:,1] -= lower; poly[:,1] *= (upper-lower); poly[:,1] *= output_res
            ImageDraw.Draw(img).polygon(poly, outline=1, fill=1)
        mask = np.array(img)
        boxed_alteration_layers.append(mask)
    return np.dstack(boxed_alteration_layers)
```

The problem is that this computation takes too long -- I have run the program for three hours for one mask on a large-memory machine and it has still not finished. The most expensive operation is computing overlapping polygons. I think that the code can  by looking over a smaller domain of polygons, excluding searching those that will *definitely not* overlap. 
Note that the poly_locator variables are [psyal.cg.locators.PolygonLocator](http://pysal.readthedocs.io/en/latest/library/cg/locators.html)s. Any advice would be appreciated. I'm not hell-bent on using Python and think that C++ might have the functionality that I need.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend the [BOOST.polygon](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/polygon/doc/index.htm) library by Lucanus Simonson.  It handles all sorts of polygon interactions, with a surprising reduction in computational complexity.  Simonson's innovative calculus to reduce the dimensionality of the 2-D problems is really neat; it left my jaw hanging open for the last 20 minutes or so of his initial proposal.

Comment: The only issue is that: "Floating point coordinate data types are not supported by the algorithms implemented in the library due to the fact that the achieving floating point robustness implies a different set of algorithms and generally platform specific assumptions about floating point representations." My polygon coordinates are lat/longs -- any recommendation on how I could get around that?

Comment: Sure; multiply by whatever factor retains the precision you need.  Do the polygon math.  Divide by the same factor when you get the results.  For instance, convert to milliseconds of arc.  Are your polygons small enough that you can treat them as planar instead of spherical?  The **polygon** library assumes Euclidean geometry.